# How to disable overwriting in Premiere Pro cc?

Tags: premiere, editing, adobe

whenever I drag a clip across the timeline and place it on top of another, the entire thing or a portion of it gets deleted, how do I disable this feature?

(I know the general work around to do this is not to do it but I would like the security that if I missed that I accidentally dragged another clip on top of another and then deleting a little bit that it won't happen)

Comment: What about if you put it in a new track? So instead of dragging it onto the clips that are already there, you drag it above them.

Answer (score 1):

There is couple solutions:

- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ Drag
- Use **Track Select Tool** to move everything before and after dragging
- Use **Insert** button (<kbd>,</kbd>) button from Source monitor

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I don't want to do! I want to disable this feature permanently. I don't want a work around

Comment: Then just put some weight on your <kbd>Alt</kbd> button =)

Comment: @user3910035 Consider that this is not a forum, if Shultc solved your issue, please accept the answer for future visitors. Might be a good idea to start with the tour: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour.